# Writing guides for writing like the Oxbridge tradition?

Tags: creative-writing, style, academic-writing, resources

I would like to know how to write in accordance with the Oxbridge tradition. I would like to know more about their writing style and if possible get a book that teaches it, or something similar to it.

An instance of the kind of writing I wish to mimic is Alasdair Macintyre’s After Virtue.

**Note:** I don't wish to get a reference to another kind of reference book. I want a book that could guide me through the writer's thinking process in that particular style, things like: how does he construct a sentence? whence the vocabulary from? etc.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there's an "Oxbridge style." That is, there's no Oxbridge writing style that's distinct from other polished and elegant styles. There are individual spins to any style, and I am sure Alasdair Macintyre has his own personal way of expressing ideas. However, what we have here is covered by general style principles - be concise, no padding, be specific, be clear, connect the ideas, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

By purest serendipity I came across a reference to a book on writing in the classic style just yesterday. http://classicprose.com/. I have not read it myself, but it was recommended by an acquaintance whose judgement I respect. It might be what you are looking for.